# How can I link the Button to another page using VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a button and it needs to be linked to another page. This is my current code.
How can we write this login in vuejs? It should go to page "/shop/customer/login"

```
 <div class="space-x-6">
  <button>Login</button>
   <button @click="$store.commit('openPaintCalculator')">
     Calculator
   </button>
</div>
```

I am early stage of learning vue.js

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `router-link` component of `vue-router`. You need to pass a prop `to` in the router-link which will accept a path.

`<router-link :to="{ path: '/shop/customer/login' }"><button>Login</button></router-link>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Vue router link which is a component of vue-router.

More info:
[Vue Official Page](https://router.vuejs.org/api/)

**Option 1:**

Note: page name should be declared in App.vue

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'page_name' }">
</router-link>
```

**Option 2**

```
<router-link :to="{ path: 'you path(/shop/customer/login)' }"><button>Login</button></router-link>
```

Comment: We aren't using router-link. is there any other way apart from router-link?

Comment: Yes there are other options to `vuerouterlink` such as `Voie` as defined on the official npm page, which is a simple router for building robust SPAs in Vue. However, I recommend using Vueroter since it is way easier to set up. If you consider using Voie let me know by mentioning me in a comment below. I'll do an answer regarding that, If this was helpful please upvote and verify. Happy Coding!

Comment: Can I simply use <a :href='""'></a> ?? vue bind ?

Comment: Yes, you may. However, it refreshes the page. Vue is a SPA which basically means it doesn't refresh. If you use `:href` it will refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use router-link you can create a method which navigates the user to your desired page. So in your component you can use [router.push()](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)

```
methods : {
  redirectToLogin(){
   router.push({ path: '/shop/customer/login'})
  }
}
```

and use this method with the @click event handler in your button.

```
<div class="space-x-6">
  <button @click="redirectToLogin()">Login</button>
   <button @click="$store.commit('openPaintCalculator')">
     Calculator
   </button>
</div>
```